# Plone Unit test has a no module found import error

Tags: python, path, plone

When I try to run unit testing on RichDocuments, I get an error:

```
[jd@jd:~/sandbox/trunk/eggs/Products.RichDocument-3.0.2-py2.4.egg/Products/RichDocument/tests]$ python ./testSetup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./testSetup.py", line 1, in ?
from Products.RichDocument.tests import base
ImportError: No module named RichDocument.tests
```

1) Does this have to do with my python path?

2) I saw [here](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/richdocument/unit-testing) it says: you may have to set the environment variables INSTANCE_HOME and SOFTWARE_HOME. The former should point to your Zope instance (the parent of your Products folder), the latter should point to the python library directory where Zope is installed, e.g. /usr/local/zope-2.8.4/lib/python.

How do I set this up? In `http://localhost:8380/manage`'s control panel, it says:

```
SOFTWARE_HOME
/home/jd/sandbox/trunk/parts/zope2/lib/python

INSTANCE_HOME
/home/jd/sandbox/trunk/parts/client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Buildout?  (If not, why not?)

If you are, make sure you have a testrunner section:

```
[test]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
eggs =
    ${buildout:test-packages}
```

Now you can run tests via: `bin/test -s PACKAGE` and your path will be set correctly

Comment: I am using buildout, I was following the directions on that site. When I tired your suggestion, I included:
    [test]
        recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
        eggs = Products.RichDocument
but when I ran buildout I got:
...
Getting distribution for 'zc.recipe.testrunner'.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a recipe being used:
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Forgot to mention that with what you're showing in the buildout snippet, that you need to set that value of "test-packages"

Comment: @vangheem Of course. But Jackie's set that.
Jackie: Use the mr.developer plugin to get the development package from source control (documented in the 'develop.cfg' file)

Answer (score 0):

That error is because the distribution package does not include the tests. If you want to run the tests for the package, you'll need to check it out, setup buildout to develop that package, and then run the tests as Auspex describes.